# django/python How to connect to a webservice by posting a json

Tags: python, django, json, httprequest

I am developing an application that connects to a web service, providing a json string with data and receiving a reply. 
I use the following code, where I build the json and try to post it:

```
def connectToService(request):
    data='foxp3 factor'
    l=[] 
    l.append(data)
    l.append(80)
    l.append(5)
    data=json.dumps({"findCitations":l})
    result = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/webservice', urllib.urlencode(data))
```

But it doesn't work. I hope that the json reply from the web service will be stored in result and then I will figure out a way to parse it, probably by deseriazizing it. Although there is much literature about it (json, simplejson, HttpPequest) and it has to be pretty simple I have not manage to do it yet. Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not you are using the [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Like

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> r = requests.post("http://www.example.com/webservice", data=payload)
>>> print r.text
```

Where payload is the parameter that you are passing .

Hope this will give you an idea

Comment: I think it is very enlightening. Thank you very much. I will try it!

Comment: @Jon Clements,I tried that but I have not achieved my target yet. I tried this in shell. After  performing the request in 'print r.text' it returns a link and no data, which is exactly the same link I see when I  put the url in the browser. From this I assume that the service didn't send any data back?
I also use headers={"Content-type":"application/json", "encoding":"utf-8"} in the r=requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers). Any comment on this? I also try to find another api available to the web to test my code. Do you have something in mind?

Comment: Ok I did it. I called the service again, but this time with the url that returned in the first call and it worked. Thanks a lot for the advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code and some error handling idea:

```
    payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
    url = "http://www.example.com/webservice"

    try:
        response = requests.post(url, data=payload)

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        message = 'This is not the domain we are looking for. URL is: %s' % url
        print e
        sys.exit(1)

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
        message = 'Too slow connection! URL is: %s' % url
        print e
        sys.exit(1)

    except Exception as e:
        message = 'Unknown Error: %(message)s URL is: %(url)s' % {'message': str(e), 'url': url}
        print e
        sys.exit(1)

    else:
        return response.json()
```